# Origin of the formula $\partial\log\det X=\operatorname{Tr}\left(X^{-1}\partial X\right) $

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, analysis, lie-groups, matrix-calculus

I found that for any first order differential operator $\partial $ acting on a square matrix $X$ we have

$$\partial\log\det X=\operatorname{Tr}\left(X^{-1}\partial X\right) $$

I'm quite sure it origins from 
$$ \det(\exp (X))=\exp (\operatorname{Tr}(X)) $$
But I get lost with the operator. I don't get how we can insert the differential inside the trace. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint** For an arbitrary square matrix $Y$, we have
$$\partial_{\epsilon} \log \det (X + \epsilon Y)\vert_0 = \left. \frac{\partial_\epsilon \det(X + \epsilon Y)}{\det (X + \epsilon Y)} \right\vert_0 = \left.\frac{\partial_\epsilon \det(X + \epsilon Y)}{\det X}\right\vert_0 = \partial_{\epsilon} \det (I + \epsilon X^{-1} Y) \vert_0.$$
On the other hand, expanding in a power series about $\epsilon = 0$ gives
$$\det (I + \epsilon Z) = I + \epsilon \operatorname{tr} Z + O(\epsilon^2) .$$

Answer (score 2):

I guess I found the answer since it is a known property of the trace that
$$ \partial \operatorname{Tr}\left(X \right) =\operatorname{Tr}\left(\partial X \right).$$
Then you have a straightforward computation from
$$ \det(\exp ( X))=\exp (\operatorname{Tr}(X)), $$
you have 
$$ \det(\exp (\log X))=\exp (\operatorname{Tr}(\log X)), $$ applying the logarithm
$$ \log \det( X)= \operatorname{Tr}(\log X), $$
and therefore deriving
$$\partial \log \det( X)= \operatorname{Tr}( X^{-1} \partial X) $$